# view to show content with future date

Tags: views, datetime

I am creating a view which shows nodes of content type Movies. Movie content type has fields name, description,rating, and release date. Fields the view displays are name ,description and release date. What I want to display those nodes only that have release date set to some future value. 
I googled a lot but did not find anything. How to do it?

Answer (score 7):

Hopefully you actually used a date field for "release date".  If so, just create a view and you normally would then in your filters add your release date field. Set it to a relative date text. Make it "greater or equal to" and insert " now" into the relative date.

[image: Screenshot of what was described]

Comment: I can't find greater or equal to operators. There is only equal to and not equal to operators. Any help on this

Comment: I made a screenshot for my answer, but geez, here you have it, no need to duplicate answers :P But I used greater, not greater or equal, as today isn't exactly future for me ;)

Comment: This answer: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/95662/12076 tells you have to find the additional operators.