# How do I add a date field that can be filtered by a relative value?

Tags: views, entities

If I create a view, I can add a filter that filters on a relative value on some built-in date field, such as *Post date*.  For instance, the screenshot below shows a filter I've created that will show articles posted in the last four days.

[image: filter with relative value]

Unfortunately, there is no date field type in core.  To get a date field type, you can install the [Date](https://drupal.org/project/date) module.  This allows you to create nice widgets for inputting dates.  However, I've found no way to filter the date fields created by the date module by a relative value (like the filter shown above for *Post date*).  There are `Is equal to` and `Is not equal to` operators, but no greater than operator, in the "Configure filter criterion" screen.

[image: filter that do not offer a relative value]

I believe that this should be possible, as is also evident from Nigel Waters's upvoted answer to this question: [view to show content with future date](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/86810/view-to-show-content-with-future-date). However, the exact steps one must take to reproduce the result shown in the upvoted answer eludes me.

Comment: It's not my answer, I only provided a screenshot. I was about to post an answer, but Nigel Waters was faster so I only added a screen to his, and my answer got deleted or not posted at all (can't remember and I'm not 10k atm). I wish I remembered how I did it :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found the solution. (Doh!)

It turns out that there is a module named **Date Views** that comes as part of the **Date** package.  If you enable this, the filter criterion screen changes, and you can use relative operators.

[image: Filter criterion]

Comment: Too simple to even remember :D Can you add a screenshot? I can't as I have chosen installed and it looks bad :P